# Inserting missing date into non nullable Datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, isqlquery

Here we have an existing database and I'm building a new system with a new database.

There I need to transfer some data from the old database table to the new database table.

I wrote this query in the SQL

```
INSERT INTO [Mondo-UAT].[dbo].[Countries] (
    [Country_Name]
    ,[Country_Code]
     ,[Note]
     
    )
SELECT [Code1]
    ,[Code3]
    ,[Name]
    
FROM  [MondoErp-UAT].[dbo].[Nations]
```

The issue is in the `[Mondo-UAT].[dbo].[Countries]` table has other columns like `Note` is a `string` and `Status` is a `bool` `CreateBy` is `int` `CreateDate` is `DateTime` . So when I run the query it returns with an error

`Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 8 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreatedDate', table 'Mondo-UAT.dbo.Countries'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated`

So I wanna know how to insert data for the **CreateDate**,**CreateBy** ,**Notes** from the above script I wrote.

Comment: The error is pretty clear and has nothing to do with multiple databases. That other table requires a value for that field. You'll have to either change the field to allow NULL or come up with a default when the source value is NULL. Would the current date make sense? Or '0001-01-01` ?

Comment: Note that tables have columns, not fields. (And a date consists of a year field, a month field and a day field.)

Comment: @jarlh No I want to know that for the ``CreateDate`` column asking for a value know. So how to pass a value to that column in the script I wrote.

Comment: @jarlh that's nitpicking and actually wrong. Dates in SQL Server are single binary values. If you try to decode them, all use various forms of an offset since an epoch and time component. No year, month or day fields

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hi guys. I know why the error is triggering. :) I want to know how to pass a default value to the ``CreateDate`` as DateTime.Now() , ``CreateBy`` column as 1 from the above query. : )

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I was not talking about physical storage format, they are all binary in the end I suppose, I was just mentioning that a date has year, month and day _fields_ - according to the SQL specification. E.g. today's date has the year _field_ value 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target table has non-nullable columns without defaults, you have to specify values for those fields when inserting data.

The easiest solution would be to modify the target table to add DEFAULT values for those fields, eg `SYSDATETIME()` for `Created`, `SYSTEM_USER` for `CreatedBy` and `''` for `Notes`. For `Status` you'll have to decide what a good default status is. `0` may or may not be meaningful.

Otherwise, these values will have to be specified in the query:

```
INSERT INTO [Mondo-UAT].[dbo].[Countries] (
    [Country_Name]
    ,[Country_Code]
    ,[Note]
    , Created
    , CreatedBy
    , Status
    )
SELECT [Code1]
    ,[Code3]
    ,[Name]
    , SYSDATETIME()
    , SYSTEM_USER
    , 0
FROM  [MondoErp-UAT].[dbo].[Nations]
```

[SYSTEM_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/system-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns the login name of the current user, whether it's a Windows or SQL Server login. This makes it a good default for user columns.

[SYSDATETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns the current time as a `DATETIME2(7)` value. If `Created` is a `DATETIMEOFFSET`, [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) should be used.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a simple one, The way I think was wrong,. Thank you again for the example. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set Default Value for **CreateDate,CreateBy,Notes** columns in the [Mondo-UAT].[dbo].[Countries] table if they are not null columns. So, When you insert data into the table and do not insert a value for these columns, the default value will be inserted.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to pass the value to the **CreateDate** I Tried in the ``Insert`` section by adding ``CreateDate`` and ``= DateTime.now()`` but can't add that way right?

Comment: yes, we can add default values by  wizard or script : ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_DateTime DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR YourColumn